# PredictionIO: Pio command not found after install

Tags: bash, command, predictionio

I am guessing that somehow PredictionIO didn't setup the path variables properly.

I used method 2 to install PredictionIO from this link here: [PredictionIO](https://docs.prediction.io/install/)

Everything installed correctly but when I typed in `pio` it says command not found. This is what I see:

[image]

When I try to start pio from finder I get this:

[image]

[image]

Kind of lost, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The pio bin is not in your $PATH probably

Comment: Thanks a lot this is all very helpful to the post /sarcasm

Comment: @BenoitLacherez I am new to mac, porting over from Windows. I'm not sure but from my understanding I would use an export command to add to it to my existing bash_profile?

Comment: And I don't believe the question is off topic, something like this would be helpful to anyone just getting predictionIO who is also new to mac

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to edit your PATH environment variable. You can do it directly in the shell:

```
$ export PATH=/Users/yourname/PredictionIO/bin:$PATH
```

However it will be set only as long as the session lasts. To make it permanent, you have to edit your bash profile file. I don't know how it is called on MacOS. On my Ubuntu, it is the `.profile` file. It is usually .profile, or .bash_profile or something like that.

$PATH is probably set in this file, so find where and edit.

My .profile file has a part in it that reads:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

I would change it to (even though it looks weird because it mixes your MacOS path and my Ubuntu ones):

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:/Users/yourname/PredictionIO/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

To get this working I simply did the following, this is for Mac Yosemite users.

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/Users/yourname/PredictionIO/bin; export PATH
```

Assuming you installed PredictionIO in that specific directory

Sidenote: I really don't like that there is so much cynicism to beginner's / semi-beginner's in certain areas it really makes me question StackOverFlow.

Comment: That's fine. However this env variable won't remain. As you told it , you should set it in bash_profile.

Comment: If you write out a better answer, I will accept it. Also if you could explain in your answer why your answer is better that would be awesome too, not just for me but other people

Answer (score 0):

pio uses its own python version, using your system's python can cause problems, you can define an alias in `.zshrc` file

```sh
alias pio='~/.platformio/penv/bin/python3 ~/.platformio/penv/bin/pio'
```